# cannot access width/height properties of PImage object in setup()

Tags: processing.js

I'm working with the PImage class. Normally I make 2 PImage objects, load an image into one of them (my input picture) and create a blank image using createImage(), which will become the output. I then use the loadPixels() method to access the data on the input, do some manipulation then set the respective output pixel to the result. I have not had any trouble with this so far.

The dimensions of the input and the output PImage objects need to be the same to make the pixel-by-pixel manipulations as straight forward as possible.

So here is the pickle:

```javascript
PImage myinput;
PImage myoutput;

void setup() {
  size(350, 350);      
  myinput = loadImage("myfile.jpg");  
  // the pic is 300 x 300

  //myoutput = createImage(myinput.width, myinput.height, RGB);
  //I've hardcoded the width and height below
  myoutput = createImage(300, 300, RGB);
}

void draw() {  
  image(myoutput, 0, 0);
}
```

The result of the above is a black square 300 x 300 which overlaps a grey canvas of 350 x 350. Given the code I've written, this is the result I would expect.

Now, in the above example, I've hardcoded the width and height of 'myoutput' with the line:

```javascript
myoutput = createImage(300, 300, RGB);
```

My question relates to the bit that follows:

Instead of hardcoding the values, I would rather do something like this:

```javascript
myoutput = createImage(myinput.width, myinput.height, RGB);
```

But it isn't working. I just get a big 350 x 350 grey box. And I'm not sure why. Though I do have my suspicions. When I work with pictures in javascript, I've got wait for the page to load (using an event listener like window.onload() {} etc.) before I can access the width/height properties of the image.

UPDATE:
I saw another post which had the following:

```javascript
/* @pjs preload="myfile.jpg"; */
```

So I just included this before I declared my PImage objects and now the following line works.

```javascript
myoutput = createImage(myinput.width, myinput.height, RGB);
```

I'm quite confused by the new piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your sketch in Java mode, you're running as Java. Java loads images **synchronously**, which means that the code won't continue running until the image is fully loaded. That's why it works in Java mode.

But when you're running using Processing.js, you're running as JavaScript. JavaScript loads images **asynchronously**, which means that the image is loaded **in the background** while your code continues. That means you aren't guaranteed that the image is done loading when the next line executes, which is why the image's `width` and `height` are unset.

The `preload` command tells Processing.js to load the images **before the sketch starts executing**, so that you're guaranteed that the image loads before you try to access its `width` and `height`.

From [the Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/preload/):

> This directive regulates image preloading, which is required when using loadImage() or requestImage() in a sketch. Using this directive will preload all images indicated between quotes, and comma separated if multiple images are used, so that they will be ready for use when the sketch begins running. As resources are loaded via the AJAX approach, not using this directive will result in the sketch loading an image, and then immediately trying to use this image in some way, even though the browser has not finished downloading and caching it.

Comment: So I need the `preload` command because I'm running this code using Processing.js, which reads as javascript which loads images asynchronously. This sits well with me, but I am confused by the syntax of the command though, because the `/* */` is something I've always used for bulky comments in javascript. Does it have a different meaning in processing? And is `preload` a Java command?

Comment: @Jozurcrunch It is a little confusing, because it's not really Java or JavaScript. It's specific to Processing.js. Technically it's a comment in both Java and JavaScript (so it's basically ignored by Java and JavaScript), but Processing.js itself detects it and loads the images. More info can be found in [the Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/preload/).

Comment: That is good to know. Is it fair then that I regard this as a quirk of Processing.js? As opposed to something fundamental to it?

Comment: @Jozurcrunch Maybe a little bit of both? It's a quirk of the fact that Processing.js is JavaScript. There are a bunch of little differences like this. More info here: http://processingjs.org/articles/p5QuickStart.html#thingstoknowusingpjs